# How to write as list comprehension?

Tags: python, for-loop, append, list-comprehension

I'm not very used to work with python and I was asked to write this code as a list comprehension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

This would be your for loop as a list comprehension assuming the i_averaged and time_interval are referenced prior to the loop.

```
 t_averaged = [t[i_averaged[i]] + time_interval/2 for i in range(len(i_averaged)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
squares = []
for x in range(10):
  squares.append(x ** 2)
# [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

using the list comprehension:

```
squares = [x ** 2 for x in range(10)]
    # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

try it yourself